# Java receiving text file inputs in REST

Tags: java, api, rest, file

Let's say I have a GET endpoint which receives a String ("this is a string") and returns a modified version of it ("This is a string!"):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
@ResponseBody
public String getText(@RequestParam String text) {
    return modified(text);
}
```

How would I adjust this code for it to receive the same piece of text in a .txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/try")
@ResponseBody
public String getText(@RequestParam("filePath") String filePath) throws 
IOException {
File file = new File(filePath);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = reader.readLine();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while (line != null) {
    builder.append(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
reader.close();
return modified(builder.toString());
```

}

Comment: this works if I provide a String path to the file, but if I send the file itself, it does not work.